# Proving sequence $x_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Proving sequence $x_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$. For $n \geq 2 , \frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{n}$.

so i write $x_n > 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{2}$.

$x_n > 1 + \frac{n-1}{2}$. Now,  $b_n = \frac{n-1}{2} $,  $b_n$ diverges $\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: $x_n > 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{2}$ is wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm $n \geq 2, \frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: What you get is $x_n <1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{2}$ which doesn't help.

Comment: Look for divergence of harmonic series, this series (i.e sequence of partial sums) is bound to show up.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_1^n \frac{1}{x} ~dx = \log(n).~$ Contrast this with the union of tall rectangles, that completely cover the corresponding region under the curve, where, for $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n-1\},~$ the rectangle from $~k~$ to $~k+1~$ is of height $~\dfrac{1}{k}.$

Comment: @coffeemath but x_n is bigger than a sequence which diverges to infinity..

Comment: @SophieClad You showed $\frac{1}{2} \ge \frac{1}{k}$ for any $k\ge 2$. Sum both sides from $k=2$ to $n$ to see that $$
\underbrace {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} +  \ldots  + \frac{1}{2}}_{(n - 1)\text{ times}} \ge x_n  - 1
$$ So you just showed that $x_n$ is at most a sequence that tends to infinity, but that could be true even if $x_n$ was convergent. You need a diverging lower bound, not an upper bound for $x_n$.

Comment: @Garyi think inequality sign is on incorrect

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect in your post. If $1/k$ is smaller than $1/2$ for any $k\ge 2$ then the sum of the $1/k$s is also smaller than the sum of the $1/2$s. Think about it. Why would the direction of the inequality suddenly be reversed?

Comment: Try it for a concrete $n$, say $n=4$. $1/2 \ge 1/2$, $1/2 \ge 1/3$ and $1/2 \ge 1/4$. Then $1/2+1/2+1/2 \ge 1/2+1/3+1/4$.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it with $1/2$s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test

Comment: @Gary thanks.... i quite see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy to show this typically involves this comparison of the sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}\right)+\cdots\geq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+4\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdots$$
This strategy was first used by Nicole Oresme around 1350.

Alternatively, on a similar process on every even term after $x_2$, you can show the sum is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}+x_n$, so the sum diverges.